# How do you know which value to take from a hashtable chain?

Tags: c++

So let's say you have 2 keys Yes and No and they both give the same index after hashing. So you will have the values Car->Motorcycle at index 2. How do you know which is the value for yes and which is for no?

Comment: A properly designed hash table would have [a mechanism to resolve collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

Comment: You won't just have the values, you will have key-value pairs, and you will return the one that has the key you're looking for.